# Vertical line problem in the detail section of Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a little problem with the vertical lines  in Detail section. In detail section at the end there is horizontal line. Also I have Report Footer section which displays total number of records. I suppressed Page Footer section. 
I would like end all the vertical lines to the last line of the records not to extend beyond the "Total"(Report Footer).
 It works fine if everything on the same page. The problem starts when the last line of the detail is on the first page and the "Total" wouldn't fit on the first page. It displays "Total" on the second page and it draws vertical lines to the end of the page.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem recently and resolved it just now. Just want to share what I did to resolve this problem for those who are stuck in this CR dilemma :).

Create a detail section below the detail section with the vertical lines then suppress it.

That's it! worked like a charm. Hope this helps.

Comment: verticle lines are not present when i select lines from toolbox it shows horizontal lines but i need a verticle line

Answer (score 1):

> Usually Crystal displays lines properly, when they start and end in
>   matching group sections (1st header - 1st footer). If they start in
>   page header and end in details for example, then result is often
>   undefined. Or from detail to page footer - result is undefined again.

An old question but thought i would add my findings. Thanks to @Arvo explanation above this led me to figure out why i had this issue. A report i was amending had a line object about 2-3 pixels over the boundary of the detail and header section, this caused the line to repeat on every single detail section regardless of intervening suppressed sections (there where no groupings).

Moving the line object so it didnt cross the boundary meant it only appeared in the detail sections it went over :)

Answer (score 0):

Do your vertical lines start and end in matching sections? Dou you have any groups defined?

Usually Crystal displays lines properly, when they start and end in matching group sections (1st header - 1st footer). If they start in page header and end in details for example, then result is often undefined. Or from detail to page footer - result is undefined again.