# Formatting Vertical Details Lines in Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, designer

I'm using Crystal Reports for VS 2008 and having trouble formatting vertical table lines in the details section.

**Too Short**

When I adjust the height of the line to exactly the height of the bottom of the section:

[image: Too Short Designer]

Then the line doesn't get applied to any items after the first in the list:

[image: Too Short Report]

**Too Long**

If I drag it past the bottom of that section, then it runs amok and fills up the entire page

[image: Way Too Long Designer]

Looks like this:

[image: Way Too Long Report]

**Failed Attempts**

I've tried a bunch of different section and line heights.  I've tried right clicking the line, clicking format object, and checking 'Extend to bottom of Section when Printing'.

I've tried the SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756003/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551371/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756003/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282937/how-to-resize-the-line-objects-in-crystal-reports), and none of them seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got it done by making an extra line and using a different line for the header and the details section.  It makes it a little harder to maintain, but looks better.

**Designer**:

[image: Better Designer]

**Report**:

[image: Better Report]